# How to clear the cache in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-7, netbeans-8

I created a project in NetBeans, and I would like to clear the NetBeans cache.

I'm running NetBeans 7.0.1 on a Windows 7 machine.

How do I do this?

Comment: In **NB7.4** _linux_: Delete files inside `/home/{user}/.netbeans/7.4/var/filehistory` and `/home/{user}/.netbeans/7.4/var/log`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Before 7.2, the cache is at `C:\Users\username\.netbeans\7.0\var\cache`. Deleting this directory should clear the cache for you.

Comment: For Version 8 see Pino's answer below [link]http://stackoverflow.com/a/17238597/1401409

Comment: Path has been changed for upper versions.I am using Netbeans V8.2 and path is C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache

Answer (score 397):

Close NetBeans before deleting the cache.

## NetBeans 7.2+, Windows 7

Cache is located in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\`.

Clear the cache using the `%USERPROFILE%` Windows variable:

```
del /s /q %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\
```

If it is set, you can also use the environment variable `%LOCALAPPDATA%`:

```
del /s /q %LOCALAPPDATA%\NetBeans\Cache\
```

## NetBeans 7.2+, Linux

Cache is at: `~/.cache/netbeans/${netbeans_version}/index/`

## Mac OS X

Cache is at: `~/Library/Caches/NetBeans/${netbeans_version}/`

See also http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir.

## Help Menu

On Windows, selecting the **Help » About** menu will display a dialog that contains the following text:

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (Build 201411181905)
Java: 1.7.0_80; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.80-b11
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_80-b15
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_CA (nb)
User directory: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2
Cache directory: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0.2
```

Regardless of operating system, the About dialog will contain the correct path to the cache directory.

Comment: Added the path for OSX and link to wiki.  Earlier version of Netbeans seem to have been in ~/.netbeans/${netbeans_version}/var/cache

Comment: for XP: C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\NetBeans\Cache

Comment: Yes, thanks so much!! This was driving me absolutely crazy, trying to track down bugs for hours that *weren't actually there* -- the class with the main method was not being found, and some custom exception classes were not being recognized as implementing `Throwable`... I just deleted the stupid cache, and now all of it works fine.

Comment: Is faster to acces with %AppData% var

Comment: Running under Netbeans 8.2, I deleted the entire cache folder on linux. Specifically, rm -rf ~/.cache/netbeans/8.2. This cured a nasty hang where Netbeats froze with 100% CPU usage while parsing a large project.

Comment: Thx, this SO answer saved my life: After a strange "java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file", deletion of the cache brought me back on track.

Answer (score 181):

The path of the cache directory is listed in the About window (menu Help/About).  Close NetBeans, then delete (or rename) the directory. NetBeans will rebuild its cache when it starts up.

Comment: Not to mention IDEs based on netbeans (like JMonkey) that might have a different directory location but for which this still works

Comment: Based on the nightmare errors I have solved by cleaning this cache, I'd say a big red "Clear Cache" button is required, along with the tooltip "In case all else fails".

Comment: @Atorian That sounds great, but having a big red "Clear Cache" button would not be a useful approach. You would need to be running NetBeans to click the big red button, and if NetBeans was running it would be using the cache directory you want to delete.

Answer (score 12):

On a Mac with NetBeans 8.1,

1. *NetBeans* → *About*
2. Find  *User Directory* path in the *About* screen
3. `rm -fr 8.1` In your case the version could be different; remove the right version folder.
4. Reopen NetBeans

Comment: and the fun starts once netbeans doesn't want to open. how then to find out user directory?

Comment: @chao Check your system logs and see why Netbeans cant start

Comment: thanks @Joseph, I went with a full reinstall of netbeans before I saw your response. also, in my case caches were in ./Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/ which is also described http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqUninstallMac

Answer (score 11):

I'll just add that I have tried to resolve reference problems caused by a missing library in the cache, and deleting the cache was not enough to solve the problem.

I closed NetBeans (7.2.1), deleted the cache, then reopened NetBeans, and it regenerated the cache, but the library was still missing (checked by looking in .../Cache/7.2.1/index/archives.properties).

To resolve the problem I had to close my open projects before closing NetBeans and deleting the cache.

Comment: I did as you've said. In 7.3 it remains the same.

Comment: thanks it worked..I just close all open project at netbean by highlighting all open project, right click and click close. Then closed netbean and delete cache at C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache

Comment: `To resolve the problem I had to close my open projects before closing netbeans and deleting the cache.` <-- This. Absolutely. I had two Project Groups, and had to close each project in both groups, close NetBeans, clear the cache, then add my projects back to my groups before it would work again. Thanks Ray!

Answer (score 9):

For Netbeans 7.4 and above in Linux, the cache is `$HOME/.cache/netbeans/7.4`.

Comment: he asks for a windows machine.

Answer (score 6):

In Window 7 the cache is located at C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/NetBeans/Cache

Answer (score 5):

The NetBeans cachedir is a directory consisting of files that may become large, may change frequently, and can be deleted and recreated at any time. For example, the results of the Java classpath scan reside in the cachedir.

**NetBeans 7.1 and older**
By default the userdir is inside a (hidden) directory called .netbeans stored in the user's home directory. The home directory is ${HOME} on Unix-like systems, and %USERPROFILE% (usually set to C:\Documents and Settings\) on Windows. The cachedir can be found in var/cache subfolder of the userdir.
As the name suggests, the userdir is unique per user. For each version of NetBeans installed, the userdir will be a unique subdirectory such as .netbeans/.
To find out your exact userdir location, go to the IDE's main menu, and choose Help > About. (Mac: NetBeans > About NetBeans).
NetBeans 7.1 allows to separate the cache directory using a switch --cachedir to a desired location.

**Examples**
A Windows user jdoe running NetBeans 5.0 is likely to find his userdir under 
C:\Documents and Settings\jdoe.netbeans\5.0\
A Windows Vista user jdoe running NetBeans 5.0 is likely to find his userdir under 
C:\Users\jdoe.netbeans\5.0\
A Mac OS X user jdoe running NetBeans 5.0 is likely to find his userdir under 
/Users/jdoe/.netbeans/5.0/ (To open this folder in the Finder, choose Go > Go to Folder from the Finder menu, type /Users/jdoe/.netbeans/5.0/ into the box, and click Go.)
A Linux user jdoe running NetBeans 5.0 is likely to find his userdir under 
/home/jdoe/.netbeans/5.0/

## For More Info

See this documentation at the NetBeans site: [NetBeans 7.2 and newer](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir)

Answer (score 4):

For NetBeans 8+ on Windows 10 there's a definitive bug with duplicate classes error which is being solved by cleaning the cache at 
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache`.

Comment: Sure, but as Joseph wrote it, cleaning this cache is a working solution. Brixdan tells us "why" and not "how", but thank hims for the info.

Answer (score 3):

Just install **cache eraser plugin**, it is compatible with nb6.9, 7.0,7.1,7.2 and 7.3:
To configure the plugin you have to provide the cache dir which is in netbean's about screen.
Then with Tools->erase cache, you clear the netbeans cache.
That is all, good luck.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40014/cache-eraser

Answer (score 2):

The cache is `C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\`, and then the version name of the folder will specify the correct cache.

You can also do this: Close the IDE. Instead, of deleting files and risking everything, rename this cache folder. Now start the IDE. Once it starts, a new cache folder will be created since the folder is not found. Now you can delete the renamed folder safely.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**
You might not need to whack your **entire** NetBeans cache.

---

My problem manifested as running a clean build didn't delete the previous `build` folder or `testuserdir` folder, while I was using NetBeans 8.0.2.

The first time I had this problem, Ray Slater's answer above helped me immensely. I had two Project Groups, and had to close each project in both groups, close NetBeans, clear the cache, then add my projects back to my groups before it would work again.

Later, this problem cropped up again with NetBeans 8.1. I closed NetBeans, and ran `ant build clean` at the command line, and it worked. When I reopened NetBeans, the problem was resolved. It occurs to me that NetBeans was keeping something open and just needed to be closed in order to delete the folders.

---

**Update**

I finally figured out what was going on. Somehow, my NetBeans "Module Suite Project" (yellow/orange puzzle piece**s** icon) had been closed and the "Module Project" (purple puzzle piece icon) **having the same exact name** as the "Module Suite Project" was open. Building clean cleaned that particular Project  correctly, but did not clean the entire Suite.

Now that I have the "Module Suite Project" opened correctly again, things work as expected. This explains why `ant build clean` worked, since it was done on the command line at the right level to clean the whole Suite.

I suspect I didn't strictly need to clean out my NetBeans cache at all though perhaps doing so actually fixed the issue of why it was only showing the "Module Project" instead of the "Module Suite Project", thereby doing the right thing when I clicked `build clean`... If I had simply realized that the Suite was no longer open and only the Project was, I could have fixed it in three seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this

### UserName=radhason

C:\Users\radhason\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache

[image]

Press Ok button , then cache folder will be shown and delete this cache folder of netbeans.