# NetBeans error: package org does not exist

Tags: java, netbeans, jdic

I just installed Netbeans IDE. I am now unable to import any org.* libs and it just says `package org does not exist`.
Also, I imported jdic.jar into the project and even though the code completion suggestions show up as org.jdesktop.*, it shows the same error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you clean your project after importing jar?  Make sure jar is listed in LIB folder of project settings.

Comment: org.* package? Do you have any project dependencies?

Comment: None at all. I am actually trying to import jdic, but anything with a package-name "org." fails.

Comment: can I get one full package name it is failing on?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Clearing the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10722287/759019) fixed it.
In windows 7 the cache is located in

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\NetBeans\...
```

On Linux, the cache is at:

```
/home/username/.cache/netbeans/...
```

On clearing the cache, and restarting netbeans, it started to recognize `org.*` imports again.

Comment: Windows folks, if you can't find AppData, search for %AppData%.  It's normally hidden.

Comment: to show hidden files: 
Open Folder Options by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Folder Options.

Click the View tab.

Under Advanced settings, click Show hidden files, folders, and drives, and then click OK.

Comment: Same problem, but this does not fix it.  Netbeans 8.0.2.

Comment: Same problem, but this does not fix it. Netbeans 8.2

Answer (score 7):

I did it easily, just click the Jframe, on Navigator tab, right-click -> Set Layout -> Absolute Layout and YEP, It works for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

org.netbeans.lib.awtextra is part of the AbsoluteLayout library. It should be added automatically by the ide whenever absolutelayout is used in the form. But if you switch to some other layout after using absolute layout, then the jar/library will be removed from the classpath and existing code making calls to the library will not compile.

- If you would like to use absolute layout, then please include the library in the project. Select 'Libraries' node in the project, right-click and select 'Add Library' and select 'Absolute Layout' library from the list of available libraries.
- If you do not wish to use absolute layout, then it is best to uncomment/remove code relying on the library and re-do the form design using the new layout.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try importing

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
```

This is part of the JDK.  If you can't find that, something is really wrong.

---

I suspect you need to add the libraries to your maven `pom.xml` file.

Comment: I just assumed that since he is using netbeans, he is using maven which is built in. (I thought it was the default)

Comment: I am not using maven. It is only the org.* imports I have an issue with. I tried clearing userdata/var/cache but it didn't help.

Comment: And you have definitely included those libraries in the project?

Comment: Wow, I just tried that step and it started to work. Extremely weird!

Comment: Could be there was a cache you missed and once it "realised" that `org.*` was there is fixed itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should redirect all the lost .jar files by exiting netbeans, then reopening it. There should be a prompt asking you to help the IDE find the .jar files. So please do so. If you aren't able to find the jar file. Clean and build the individual packages. There a new directory called a dist directory will be created in the package directory. Now you can redirect them.

Answer (score 0):

Above was not working for me so I tried below and its working:

1. Google "absolutelayout.jar download"
2. Download jar
3. Open NetBeans and Add this "AbsoluteLayout-RELEASE***.jar" file to your project Library folder.
4. now try to run the project/file

Answer (score 0):

in my experience the problem was with a Jpanel with AbsoluteLayout, I put free-design and solved the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).