# Package org not found - Parse4J & Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, import

I've been trying to use Parse4J on NetBeans, but everytime I try to import some stuff from org.parse4j, Netbeans underlines it, saying that the package org does not exist.

I have imported the jar by right-clicking Libraries and selecting "Add Jar/Folder", I have deleted the cache according to this post (ie : del the appdata/local/Netbeans/Cache folder) :

[NetBeans error: package org does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760333/netbeans-error-package-org-does-not-exist)

But to no avail.
I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong here. Any advice ?

Comment: when choosing "Add Jar/Folder". Did you select folder or that specific jar? It happens when we select the folder rather than that specific jar.

Comment: I selected the specific jar.

Comment: cannot think of alternative; clear cache-> restart net beans and try. if not working i cannot think of any other option than create new project since there must be some issues with build file. Also open the jar and see if the intended class file is already there. at times the jar is corrupted during download.

Comment: I'll try create a new project then. Thanks !
(NB : yeah, the jar doesn't seem corrupted, it has all the classes it has to have)