# Netbeans Web Services JAX-WS package does not exist

Tags: soap, netbeans, jax-ws, netbeans-7, netbeans-8

please help. I am new in web services and for the moment I am trying this tutorial https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html , ( this is one of the lessons that I attend at school ) unfortunately I can't understand way netbeans generate errors.

The web service worsk fine, but on the client side ( **I had created the web service client by specifying the WSDL URL** )

1) Web service:
[image: web service]

2) Client side:
[image: client side]

I am mentioning that I get the same result on Netbeans 8.1. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in this link: [NetBeans error: package org does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760333/netbeans-error-package-org-does-not-exist)

Answser: "Clearing the cache fixed it. by Anirudh Ramanathan"