# Netbeans GUI builder - output different at run time than in programming display

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, netbeans, textarea

I am hoping someone can help me.

I am programming a GUI (and program) in netbeans and have run into a weird situation whereby what the application looks like in netbeans preview is NOT what comes out when I run the file - instead an older version of the GUI is displayed.

Specifically, in the netbeans programming environment I have a TextArea in the bottom right of the GUI. When I run the program this TextArea is gone and the only thing that shows is a previous version of the GUI that only had a jPanel.

I have cleaned and clean and build the project and rebooted the computer but this action persists.

Please help!!

Comment: Please add some source code ...

Comment: did you try to enlarge your panel at runtime to see if the button is not a little bit more far in the lower right corner?

Comment: Rebooting the computer seems like a religion to be. Instead, use a version control system and commit your project. Then delete your panel and redo it. Once the new one is working, use a diff to see the difference.

Comment: I'm sorry - Ive been a little unclear. The opens full screen and there is definitely nothing outside of the visible.

Comment: Did you take a close look at the source code of the function generated by NetBeans?

Comment: Instead - I have a a blank JPanel with a old border title. I not longer wanted that - instead wanted a jTextArea area here with a different border title. So I have gone ahead and created that in Netbeans. But - while I see it in netbeans and preview it in netbeans - the change does not come out when running the file. It still has the OLD layout. As regards rebooting - well yes, not a normal action but I was trying to see if netbeans would refresh some "image" it was holding in place and using rather than my new code...

Comment: had a look just now and despite putting it in place visual (drag and drop) it is not updating the auto generated code - any ideas why this would be?

Comment: Try shift-f11 (clean and rebuild), then hit f6 to run, and see if that clears it up.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the NetBeans cache. I've had issues with older GUI visuals and other Java errors (once it claimed I had a duplicate class) and clearing the cache fixed those problems when cleaning and cleaning and building has not. I deleted the entire cache folder; I can't comment on the reliability or security or other issues of such an action, but I haven't had any adverse experiences.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689780/clearing-cache-in-netbeans) about finding the cache directory based on your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to save, delete, and redo the GUI file.

Comment: I have deleted those elements and redone them from scratch - there were a few - but I still dont know what cause Netbeans to "hiccup" like this. Any feedback on this welcome.

Comment: Does it work now? I have no idea why NetBeans would do that. Which version are you using, by the way?