# What causes "bad operand types for binary operator '==' "with second type <nulltype>?

Tags: java, netbeans

When I check if the instance of StoredCredential is null

```
if(storedCredential != null){
  //do something
}
```

Netbeans 7.1 shows the following warning:

```
bad operand types for binary operator '=='
  first type:  com.blah.dbcore.mypublic.beans.StoredCredential
  second type: <nulltype>
```

It compiles correctly and throws no RuntimeExceptions, but Netbeans still shows the warning.
Checking if the instance is not null, with '!=', gives the same error.

The following code does the same thing, but is a lot less clear:

```
if (!(storedCredential instanceof StoredCredential)) {
  //do something
}
```

Netbeans has no problem with this expression.

Because it has no problem compiling, I'm assuming there is something wrong with the way I added the .jar containing the class to the library. This is the only problem I'm having with this jar though, no other class in this .jar gives me this problem.

Comment: first of all, you probably mean `netbeans 7.1` not `netbeans 1.7`. but what is the type of storedCredential?

Comment: If your error mentioned for example the operator '|=', then all would be clear since that one operates only on numbers and booleans.

Comment: @alegen Oops, yeah, netbeans 7.1, fixed it :P  The type is StoredCredential extends Bean, which is an Object that implements Serializable, nothing special I think. I did notice a transient field in the Bean class, but I don't think that would give this sort of problem.

Comment: I've had Netbeans getting confused about what is actually written in a java file before, so perhaps restarting or [clearing it's cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689780/clearing-cache-in-netbeans) would simply make this go away? Always worked like magic for me when stuff that seemingly defied logic occured. Do backup before clearing though.

Comment: @predi I've exited Netbeans, cleared the cache and started it up again. The problem is still there. I also found that if I type `storedCredential.` Netbeans does not give any hints.

Comment: @marcoPogo: Is everything else in the project building correctly or do you have other compile errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this issue, too.  Also, where I tried to pass an instance of the problem class into a method which accepted an Object as a parameter, I got the following error:

```
required: String,Object
found: String,SomeClass
reason: actual argument SomeClass cannot be converted to Object by method invocation conversion
```

Turned out the compiler was unable to determine the correct type of my class.

My class (let's call it com.blah.lib.SomeClass) was in one NB project (let's call it Project 1) and extended a class in a 3rd party jar, which was a library for Project 1.

Another NB project (let's call it Project 2) depended on Project 1 and used com.blah.lib.SomeClass, but did not have the 3rd party jar in its libs, so when compiling Project 2, the compiler was unable to determine the full inheritance of com.blah.lib.SomeClass.

So the solution was to add the 3rd party jar to Project 2's libraries, too.

I know this is years old, but I thought I'd post this answer in case it helps anyone else Googling the issue in the future.

Comment: Oh wow, I had forgotten this question was still open, but this was indeed the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans is telling you that at that point in the program, `storedCredential` cannot possibly be null. This probably means that you already called a method or accessed a data member on `storedCredential` earlier in that method.