# Java in NetBeans. No access to nested public class and enum

Tags: java, netbeans

Here's part of the code in Category.java

```
public class Category

    {
        static public final class range
        {
            public range( double lower, double upper )
            {
                this.lower = lower;
                this.upper = upper;
            }
            public double lower;
            public double upper;
        }    
    static public Map< category_type, range > validCategoryRanges = new EnumMap<>(category_type.class);
    ...
```

When access is needed in other files of same package, there's no such class, only field validCategoryRanges is seen. (In Eclipse it worked).

Comment: Do you not get auto completion, or does it actually not compile?

Comment: It does not show inner class and enum as available member when using dot operator on outer class.

Comment: What version of netbeans are you using? In any case, you can pretty much ignore it and just write the name out, it will compile either way.

Comment: Maybe you can try deleting your netbeans cache. [clearing-cache-in-netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689780/clearing-cache-in-netbeans)

Comment: I've found it. Any enum name I put is available in dot operator pop up list. Once I put category_type, it's not seen.

Comment: It did not also take range nested class. Why it happened? After I cleaned caches ( as such name could exist, I decided there's a collision so IDE does not show it ) it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your nested classes outside the initialisation block, just like any member variable. This should have nothing to do with whatever IDE that you are using.
    public class OuterClass
    {
       public static final class InnerClass
       {
       }
    }