# How to tell Netbeans IDE not to open previously opened projects on startup

Tags: netbeans, crash, project

My netbeans seems to freeze every time I try to open it.  It says `waiting projects opened`.  I want to somehow clear the list of 'open projects' so that netbeans doesn't try and open them automatically on startup.

Maybe clearing the cache or something?

I'm running Netbeans 7.3 on Mac OS: X Mountain Lion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Clear netbeans cache:**

Clearing the cache in Netbeans will probably cause it not to load previously opened projects: [Clearing Cache in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689780/clearing-cache-in-netbeans)

Comment: Sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't.  I had 4 projects opened when I closed down NB.  I deleted the cache folder and, when I started NB again, it started to open all the previous projects.  This happens with NB 7.4 on Windows 8.

Answer (score 6):

A little late, but I think 
`config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/projectui.properties` is the file you are (were?) looking for.

Mine (Netbeans 8.1 on a GNU/Linux box) is located under `%my_home_dir%/.netbeans/8.1/`, like:

`/home/scherrer/.netbeans/8.1/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/projectui.properties`

I've made a test renaming this file and when I opened the IDE no project was opened.

Comment: This just solved my issue. I deleted projectui.properties and netbeans opens again. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Clearing cache in `Netbeans` is not enough to avoid the load of the projects, instead you can close temporaly the projects.

With <kbd>shift</kbd>+Click you can select several projects to be closed:

[image]

Comment: But this requires first opening Netbeans & having it open those projects -- which is what the original question was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and i solved it this way

1. Kill netbeans
2. Change the name of the folder where you have your projects
3. Open netbeans
4. re rename the folder to the original name
5. Open your projects one by one