# Clear cache in netbeans 7.3

Tags: netbeans-7

I want to clear my netbeans cache because when I try to run my project, it is showing the error "Low memory to run this project" and

```
C:\Users\Nidhi\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.3\executor-snippets\run.xml:48: 
Cancelled by user.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 19 seconds)
```

But if I delete my cache folder (C:\Users\Nidhi\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache) I think some of the registry files are also deleted because my netbeans stops working... How can I delete my local history?

Answer (score 0):

Please post the full error message.

BTW I do not think the error message is about disk space. It is about unsufficient heap/perm gen.

Comment: actually my problem is netbeans is using too much RAM (500+ mb) in my system, thats why its showing this error message and I dont know how to reduce its Ram usage.I am using Windows 7

Comment: 500 MB heap is nothing spectacular. I would buy a DIMM of RAM instead of hoping for a software solution. BTW Did you try to use a more recent version of NB? 8.0RC1 has been released some days ago.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10722287/7409132) from user133408 could help you.

Clear the cache using the `%USERPROFILE%` Windows variable:

```
del /s /q %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\
```