# How to clear cache in NetBeans 8.0 OS X

Tags: netbeans, osx-mavericks, netbeans-8

How do I clear the cache in NetBeans 8.0 on OSX Mavericks?

[Previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689780/how-to-clear-the-cache-in-netbeans) have suggested that I remove the files under

- `/home/{user}/.netbeans/7.4/var/filehistory` and
- `/home/{user}/.netbeans/7.4/var/log`

but the hidden folder `.netbeans` appears to be absent on my computer. Has it moved?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check menue `NetBeans > About` menu, it shows path to cache dir. The paths you posted look like for Linux, on Mac it is (at least with recent versions of NetBeans) something like

```
/Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/Caches/NetBeans/8.0/
```

Comment: With my macOS, it's `/Users/user/Library/Caches/NetBeans/x.y`.

Answer (score 21):

Go to Netbeans > About and at the bottom you can find the Cache directory. Copy that directory, command + shift + g in the finder, paste the directory and BOOM you're there.

Comment: I would like to know what kind of information from cache is deleting??

Answer (score 6):

According to NetBeans [FAQ on UserDir and CacheDir](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir):

> Mac OS X **/Users//Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.0/**
>
> Windows: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0\
>
> Unix-like systems: /home//.cache/netbeans/8.0

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Help` -> `About` and you will see

**Cache directory:** Path\to\Directory

go to specified directory and delete everything.

Answer (score 0):

In version netbeans 12.0 path :

Cache directory: /Users/sinjugu/Library/Caches/NetBeans/12.0

Hope for help.

Answer (score -2):

You can find the path by opening the `About Netbeans` dialog in Netbeans.