# Netbeans 8.0.2 `scan for external changes` suspended, and no auto popup

Tags: netbeans, autoload, freeze

I am using NetBeans as my IDE. After working a few hours,  I got the following problems

**1. It got stuck with scan for external changes suspended**

**2. and after this came, the `auto-load` also got fails. It shows `please wait...` only.**

Due to this I am planning to change my IDE. Is there any way to overcome this? I thought it was due to the issue with my slow computer. I just formatted and upgraded it. Then also it shows the same issue.

My NetNeans is the small package with `PHP` and `HTML` only.

**3. It also cause `high CPU usage` sometimes**

My operating system is Windows 8.1 with 4 GB memory and i3 processor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should close your old projects that you are not working. You clears your netbeans cache as well. 
You can get help about clear [netbeans cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689780/how-to-clear-the-cache-in-netbeans) from here

Comment: this didnt worked for me tho, a specific project hangs at 2 different machines