# Netbeans shows "unable to resolve identifier", but builds and runs code

Tags: c++, netbeans

I'm working on a c++ project in netbeans for some weeks. 
Some days ago netbeans started to show

```
Unable to resolve identifier
```

for each variable through the whole code.
**But the code still works**. It can be succesfully build.

So there's actually no problem with my code, but all those red lines are pretty annoying.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to run project reparse: `Project Context menu - Code Assistance - Reparse Project` and [clear netbeans cache](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10722287/4074081).

Comment: Reparsing worked! Thanks frymode!