# Java Netbeans: 'Package does not exist'

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a problem with my code, even though it hasn't been modified in any way. It just suddenly threw this message. As you can see on the left, that they are all in the correct package, and have correct names.
What can I do to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding the problem.  Eclipse, and I assume netBeans gets confused periodically.

Comment: Right click on project then select clean and build....then try

Comment: The option to clean and rebuild in the Tools drop down menu is greyed out, it won't allow me to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689780/how-to-clear-the-cache-in-netbeans/10722287#10722287) the cache to fix it. In Windows, cache is located at:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\NetBeans\...
```

On Linux, cache is at:

```
/home/username/.cache/netbeans/...
```

After clearing the cache restart netbeans.

Comment: on Mac OS on ~/Library/Caches/NetBeans/${netbeans_version}/
For this kind of problem it is enough to delete the subfolder ./index/ only.

Answer (score 0):

If clearing the cache still doesn't work try adding the jar files **themselves** instead of adding the folder. Looks like a bug in Netbeans. I did it that way and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had some compiled classes from a JAR which I wanted to include in my project. I created a new package, I added the complied classes in and then got this "package does not exist" error when trying to import the new package.

If you're adding compiled Java classes and getting this error, here's how I solved it:

1. Create the package
2. Add a new (empty) Java Class (.java file) to the package, using the same name as the compiled Java class.
3. At this point, you should see your broken references to "package does not exist" or to the class file you just added are fixed.
4. Delete the new .java file and NetBeans should still see the package with the newly added classes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem after we moved our NFS mount point containing my root project directory.

It seems there were some references to the old mount point in the `.nb-gradle` directory.

I closed all the projects in Netbeans and terminated Netbeans.  I moved `.nb-gradle`to `hidden.nb-gradle` (*and .nb-gradle-properties to hidden.nb-gradle-properties for good measure*). I restarted NetBeans and reopened the root project (*which auto-opened the subprojects*).

The `does not exist` message and all cascaded errors went away.  A new `.nb-gradle` directory was created in the root project directory.  The `.nb-gradle-properties` file was not re-created.