# How to enable JavaFX in NetbeansIDE 11.3

Tags: javafx, netbeans, netbeans-11

I can't get JavaFX working with NetBeans 11.3.

The [NetBeans documentation](https://netbeans.org/kb/72/java/javafx-setup.html) says:

> If you install JavaFX 2.1 to Windows manually, consider installing the JavaFX 2.1 libraries and runtime to the default location (C:/Program Files/Oracle/). NetBeans IDE checks the default locations for the JavaFX. If JavaFX 2 is in the default locations the IDE can automatically create a JavaFX-enabled Java platform.

I've put the Gluon SDK there, though the number is 11.0.2. NetBeans does not automatically create a JavaFX enabled platform.

This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361254/java-netbeans-package-does-not-exist/35361572) suggests cleaning the cache. That didn't help.

If I try to create a new JavaFX project from the IDE, I get the message:

> Failed to automatically set-up a JavaFX Platform. Please go to Platform Manager, create a non-default Java SE platform, then go to the JavaFX tab, enable JavaFX and fill in the paths to valid JavaFX SDK and JavaFX Runtime. Note: JavaFX SDK can be downloaded from JavaFX website.

But there is no "JavaFX" tab on the platform manager. The [NetBeans release notes way back in version 8.0.2](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/relnotes.html#javafx) say:

> Unlike previous versions of NetBeans IDE, NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 does not require that you set up an "FX-enabled" Java platform in order to utilize JavaFX support in the IDE. You can develop JavaFX projects in the IDE if you install any standard Java platform that is JDK 7 Update 6 or newer (JDK 7 Update 10 or newer is strongly recommended).

But presumably that is from when JavaFX was bundled in the JDK.

So how *do* I get NetBeans to recognise the Gluon JavaFX?

Answer (score 0):

Manual workaround:

/nbproject/project.properties file

```
run.jvmargs=--module-path "D:\\Libraries\\Java9\\openjfx-13.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\\javafx-sdk-13.0.2\\lib" \
--add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web \
--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED \

// you may need to add more --ad-exports arguments based on the errors that will crop up during the run phase. this stuff basically removes package access limiters at runtime so be careful.
```

then there's the compiler arguments

```
javac.modulepath=\
    D:\\Libraries\\Java9\\openjfx-13.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\\javafx-sdk-13.0.2\\lib
```

and i'm pretty sure you need this too

```
javac.classpath=\
${libs.JAVAFX13.classpath}:\
```