# hint in Netbeans about setting project default for my Web App messed all my HTML files up

Tags: html, css, netbeans

So I was trying to do an include on a file, and all of sudden it caused a hint to pop up at the top of my jsp page, the hint was on the `<html>` tag. I hover over it and it gives me all kinds of option about setting the project default. Here is a snippet of the hints:

> Change project default: XHTML5
>
> Change project default: XHTML 1.0 Strict
>
> Change project default: XHTML 1.0 Transitional
>
> Change project default: XHTML 1.0 Frameset
>
> Change project default: XHTML 1.1

I accidentally clicked one of them. As to which one I am unsure, but it has now caused every single file with HTML in it to have errors or warnings and telling me my HTML classes cannot be found from the main CSS file. I tried checking out a fresh version from my repository, but this did not fix it. The errors are still there. I am assuming it has something to do with Netbeans. I am currently running 8.2 version. The project is a web application.

[image: Picture of Hints]

The hint/error says:

> The XHTML version of the code cannot be determined. You can set the
>   default value of this project.

I have always had that same URL in my HTML tag since I can remember and have never had any issues. I just tried removing it, and the hint suggested setting the HTML project default. I set the default to HTML5, but my classes for my tags are still not being found.

### Update: removed the XHTML URL in my HTML tag and solved the issue with HTML errors

I still have an issue with my classes from main CSS file being found, currently, all my styles are linked to one single file, which is included on every single page on my website. So there should be no issue with finding them, I have always done this and it has worked for months.

This is how I linking my CSS in my `metaHeader.jspf` page:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: If you post a screenshot it would be helpful to understand the problem clearly.

Comment: Are these xml or html / xhtml?

Comment: @NicholasSmith They are HTML, removing the url fixed the issue with the HTML errors, but now my classes are still no longer being found.

Comment: So your html tag is now just `<html>`?   And what does your CSS include line look like?

Comment: @NicholasSmith just updated the question :)

Comment: Have you tried clearing Netbeans cache? Location of file dependent on OS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689780/how-to-clear-the-cache-in-netbeans

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearing cache did not work, so I decided to uninstall Netbeans and everything is working like normal. It was definitely something off with Netbeans. I have been doing this website the same way for the past year with no issues like this.