# The constructor Scanner(InputStream) is undefined

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have imported java.util.* but the IDE can't recognize Scanner. If I change it to import java.util.Scanner; it's fine. But I need it on java.util.* because the catch exception is part of java.util. This code is from a textbook by the way.

EDIT: I'm using Eclipse.

```
import java.util.*;

public class GetInteger {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        int i = GetAnInteger();
        System.out.println("You entered " + i);
    }

    public static int GetAnInteger() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                return sc.nextInt();
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                sc.next();
                System.out.println("That's not an integer. Try again: ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which IDE is is that?

Comment: Probably Netbeans, since I have tried in Eclipse and it works. Anyway, I don't recommend to use `import java.util.*;` but import only classes you really are about to use.

Comment: Use a different ide, like intellij.

Comment: Clear the cache of your IDE. i.e Netbeans (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689780/how-to-clear-the-cache-in-netbeans)

Comment: I'm using Eclipse

Comment: You probably have defined a class Scanner in the same package as GetInteger. If that's really code from a book, I'd definitely read another one: a book that can't even respect the standard Java naming conventions is most probably not worth reading.

Comment: Fixed. You were right, there was another class in the package called Scanner that I forgot to delete.