# Netbeans caching incorrect, old environment variable

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8.2

I'm using Netbeans 8.2 on Linux and we have changed our Boost version and therefore environment variable pointing to boost. However, Netbeans seems to be using a cached version, even though our compile script forces to reload the current one. If I echo the variable on a terminal (even terminal within Netbeans) I get the correct value.

Is anyone acquainted with where Netbeans cache this, where is this cache and is it okay to delete this cache?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear the cache in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689780/how-to-clear-the-cache-in-netbeans)

Comment: [1] For NetBeans 8.2 specifically, see [this answer by Pino](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17238597/2985643) for the linked duplicate question. [2] Also see [What is a cachedir and where can I find it?](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir). [3] It is always safe to delete the cache directory (as long as NetBeans is not running), and it should not cause any issues other than a minor performance hit when deleted cached data gets recreated.