# Netbeans 11 don't show native php functions

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-11

I have a problem with netbeans 11 PHP project. Autocomplete native PHP functions ( for example substr) in project not work, but my classes or functions is OK. PHP plugin is activated.

Thanks for help.
L.

Answer (score 2):

Work for me:
Stop IDE,
Clear NetBeans cache,
Start IDE

Comment: To clear Netbeans Cache, the cache folder has to be deleted. See this answer for where to find the cache dir: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10722287/3099003