# Many Error displays in netbeans with codename one

Tags: codenameone

I can compile a simple app fine using codename one and netbeans. but my editor displays many errors all over making my code ugly and unreadable. See attached screenshot

[image: netbeans]

Its very buggy. The first string displays no error but all the other ones do, but the code compiles and works fine. What the hell ?

also autocomplete dosent seem to work. but works fine with real java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a problem in Netbeans. Typically quitting netbeans and deleting the caches directory forces a rescan which usually resolves that. See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10722287/756809

Comment: How annoying, that was the problem. All fixed now, your a legend.