# What should I do if there is a warning after download NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

Today I used NetBeans to write code, but it suddenly crashed, running very slow, and can't open anything. I tried to delete it and download it again, but when I just downloaded it and opened it, it gave the following problem:

> org.netbeans.InvalidException:
> StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.parsing.ui jarFile:
> /Applications/NetBeans/Apache NetBeans
> 17.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/ide/modules/org-netbeans-modules-parsing-ui.jar:
> Layer not found: org/netbeans/modules/parsing/ui/layer.xml

I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: It's possible that your downloaded file is invalid or corrupt. From the NetBeans 17 Release Notes, with my emphasis added: [_"Officially, **it is important that you verify the integrity of the downloaded files** using the PGP signatures (.asc file) or a hash (.sha512 files)."_](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb17/). So repeat your download, and then [verify that the file has been downloaded correctly](https://www.apache.org/info/verification.html) before using it.

Comment: And/or maybe delete the cache (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689780/how-to-clear-the-cache-in-netbeans)