Netbeans does not show project files
I am using a Mac and have Netbeans 1.4.0 with TMC and JDK both installed, doing perfectly fine. When I try to open a downloaded exercise from MOOC, netbeans just shows empty folders. However, in Finder, there are clearly files in these project folders. All projects downloaded are like this, in which the project files are not visible on Netbeans but are on Finder.
What Netbeans shows
What is actually in the folders
I tried reinstalling both JDK and netbeans several times, but it does not work.
I tried looking online but not many people have had this issue it seems. It's either that or I cannot find their post.
No, double clicking the folder does not work, nor does restarting netbeans work.
Dragging the file from Finder to Netbeans does not work either
It's already been a few days. Please help me.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it's currently written it’s not possible to say what is the issue. See the
[ask] to understand how to write a question for [so]. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to
reproduce the issue. See [mre]. How did you open the project that has problems and how did you open a project without issues? Note that both images show the same information. Avoid using images for issues that are not graphical.

I would try few things.

Open part01-Part01_01.Sandbox file with File->Open Project.
Refresh project tree
remove netbeans cache.
Open netbeans log file (help->view log)

I hope this works!

What is the project tree and how do I remove the NetBeans cache? Sorry, I am completely new to NetBeans so..

Maybe you should start learning how Netbeans works.

It'd help more if you were to just tell me how.

Deleting the cache: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689780/how-to-clear-the-cache-in-netbeans
