# How do I resolve Netbeans "cannot find symbol" in working tests?

Tags: netbeans-8

I have this issue where NetBeans will highlight and throw "cannot find symbol" errors in the editor in some of my unit tests.  It doesn't afflict all tests, nor does it happen to all objects used in the tests (most of which are in the exact same source directory).  It also does not impact running the tests...  The code runs fine in and outside of NetBeans as do the tests.  Yet, the NetBeans IDE insists that *some* of the objects referenced in the unit tests cannot be found.

It's very consistent which unit tests are impacted.  *Sometimes* merely opening the referenced object source files will cause the IDE to correct itself and remove the false alerts.  Sometimes not though...

Is there some configuration option I might have missed?  The source and test directory properties are pointing to the correct places (if they were wrong I'd expect *everything* to be wrong too).

Comment: Which versions of Java and NetBeans are being used?

Comment: It's terribly intermittent and has happened with various versions of NetBeans and Java, going back years.  I posted up recently because it finally seemed to be reproducible, but now it's magically fine again.  I changed nothing about it, but the problem is once again gone.  Sigh.

Comment: It's back again, and oddly now it's ALL of my unit tests instead of just a couple.  Java 8U152 (b16) x64 and NetBeans 8.2 (201705191307)

Comment: Do any of the suggestions here help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298854/what-is-causing-this-java-cannot-find-symbol-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is causing this Java "Cannot find symbol" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298854/what-is-causing-this-java-cannot-find-symbol-error)

Comment: Well, I can't duplicate it now.  It's so intermittent.  I'm going to tag this to be closed as a duplicate of that other question anyways though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's probably just a NetBeans thing as it comes and goes.  Oddly it will stay throughout shutdowns/restarts, but at some point perhaps some config file is rewritten...  Dunno.