# Why can't NetBeans & Java find Swing's contents?

Tags: java, swing

After over a decade, I decided to blow the dust off my university dissertation and get it working again.

Oddly, NetBeans can't seem to find the libraries for `javax.swing`. Every single thing I imported for `javax.swing` can no longer be found with "cannot find symbol" for `javax.swing.JFrame`, `javax.swing.JLabel` etc.

I can't find where the library would be to import it!

Should I be using a different version of the JDK? Do I have to download `javax` from somewhere and include it?

[image]

Comment: I'm stumped for an answer myself, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298854/what-is-causing-this-java-cannot-find-symbol-error) seems to describe a similar problem.  If you haven't already, I would try some of the solutions proposed over there.

Comment: Is it finding *any* JDK classes? You're online importing swing classes (without stars) so it's impossible to tell whether this is a problem with swing, or whether perhaps your JDK is not set up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by downloading a different JDK (1.8, which I think contains JDK 8) from oracle. Works now. Maybe the other JDK I downloaded is too new, and there were changes to the packages, or maybe it didn't include all the packages. Either way, done now.